How to get good quality image on the monitor via MacBook?
I own a MacBook Pro 14 (2021) on M1. I recently bought a 27*inch 1920x1080 (240Hz) monitor.
When connecting to a Mac via HDMI I get poor image quality. The text seems to be crumbling, pixels are visible. In general, it hurts the eyes.
BUT! Connecting to another laptop (Xiaomi Gaming laptop 2016) - through the same HDMI I get a very clear picture and text. Very nice to watch and work.
Why does Mac produce such poor quality? I tried to change the display settings through other +Hi Dpi utilities. Did not help. It's like the screen resolution has been halved.
Or do you need to connect via other connectors for a Mac? The monitor comes with a Display Port cable, I’m thinking of buying an adapter for it (to Type C) - will this help?
